# bash - which is the most efficient way of using string length in a loop?

Tags: bash, performance

Can someone confirm which of the two code snippets below has the lower time complexity or if they are equivalent?

```
str="a very long string"
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#str} ]; do
  ((i++))
done
```

Or,

```
str="a very long string"
str_len=${#str}
i=0
while [ $i -lt $str_len ]; do
  ((i++))
done
```

I'd appreciate it if you can also point to any existing doc.

Comment: `for ((i=0; i<str_len; i++)); do echo $i; done` might be better that any of these 2

Comment: BTW, `[ $i -lt $str_len ]` without the quotes is string-splitting and glob-expanding each value. `[ "$i" -lt "$str_len" ]` allows a shell to do less work (not asserting that bash takes advantage of that to actually be faster with the quoting in place, but asserting that it this is a more easily-optimized form: A **future** version of the shell could do same, as could a different/better-written shell).

Comment: ...if you want a POSIX-compliant shell that actually has good runtime performance, though? bash is **completely** the wrong tool for the job; use ksh93... or, better, a non-shell language altogether.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Calculating `strlen()` once is going to be ever so slightly cheaper than calculating it once per iteration.

That said, if you're working in an application where you expect this difference to matter, you're using the wrong tool for the job. bash doesn't document/define runtime performance characteristics at all, and such characteristics are generally summarizable as "bad".